# Did Ramakrishna eat cow's meat during his time as a muslim?

Tags: other-religions, ramakrishna, prabhupada

Srila Prabhupada during a conversation about sakhibekhi(one of thirteen apasampradayas) mentions about Ramakrishna which can be read [here](https://www.harekrsna.com/philosophy/gss/sadhu/apasampradayas/sakhibekhi.htm)

> Hari-sauri: Oh, he became a woman sometimes.
>
> Prabhupada: Yes, sometimes. And there was menstrual, menstruation
> period. He became so perfect, there was menstruation. (laughter) This
> rascal Ramakrishna did it. **And he was going to make experiment of the
> Muhammadan realization by eating...**
>
> Hari-sauri: Meat.
>
> Prabhupada: **...go-mamsa, cow's flesh.**
>
> Hari-sauri: I think you said that he...
>
> Prabhupada: Yes.
>
> Hari-sauri: **...was refused entry into some temple because of that**

So is it true that Ramakrishna during his time as a muslim, when he stopped worshipping Hindu Gods, ate cow's meat(beef) and for this he was not allowed entry in a particular temple?

Answer (score 8):

Swami Nirantarananda in [Prabuddha Bharata (October, 2006)](https://advaitaashrama.org/pb/2006/102006.pdf) says that Ramakrishna had developed a deep urge for consuming beef but was requested by a disciple not to eat.

> #### Sri Ramakrishna: The Embodiment of All Religions
>
> Swami Nirantarananda
>
> ...
>
> Hindu devotees would be stunned to know that **Ramakrishna wanted to
> eat beef when he was practising Islam**. It was only at Mathurmohan
> Biswas's solicitous request that he refrained from doing so. The
> Master said, 'I then devoutly repeated the holy name of Allah, dressed
> like the Muslims, and said their prayers several times a day. Because
> the Hindu feeling had disappeared from my mind altogether, I felt
> disinclined to visit the Hindu deities, much less to bow down to
> them.'

However, Ram Swarup, in [*Ramakrishna Mission: In Search of a New Identity*](https://archive.org/details/Identity_201605/page/n9/mode/2up) cites [Akshay Kumar Sen](https://belurmath.org/akshay-kumar-sen/)'s hagiography [*Ramakrishna Punthi*](https://archive.org/details/16SriSriRamakrishnaPunthi/mode/2up) (translated from Bengali verse form to English prose, as [*A Portrait of Sri Ramakrishna*](https://books.google.com/books?id=63jXAAAAMAAJ)) as saying he consumed beef "astrally" through a dog's body:

> During his practice of Islam, Ramakrishna "repeated the mantra Allah, and said Namaz thrice daily." During this while he also dressed and ate like a Muslim. Another hagiograpical work, Ramakrishna Punthie by Akshoy Sen provides some more news. A Muslim cook was brought who stood outside the kitchen and instructed a Brahmin cook made to wear a lungi, inside how to cook in a Muslim way.
>
> We are also told that at this time, Ramakrishna felt a great urge to take beef. **However, this urge could not be satisfied openly. But one day as he sat on the bank of the Ganges, a carcass of a cow was floating by. He entered the body of a dog astrally and tasted the flesh of the cow. His Muslim Sadhana was now complete.**

Comment: But why he had to practice Islam? Is there any mentioning on same?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Check [this](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/sriramakrishna_thegreatmaster/srkgrtmaster_files/Sri%20Ramakrishna%20-%20The%20Great%20Master-28.html) link. (11. The Master’s resolve afer talking with Govinda: The Master was attracted towards the devout Govinda, and happening to converse with him, was charmed with Govinda’s sincere faith in and love for God. Thus was the Master’s mind now attracted towards the Islamic religion.)

Comment: Thanks bro! @sv. So he was already a realized being when he got attracted to Islam. And thence he saw no difference in Islam and Vedanta.

Comment: I think It's not easy to understand sages of Dharma.

Comment: <<He entered the body of a dog astrally>> That itself means he is a great saint

Answer (score 2):

Initiated by Sufi Govinda, [the Master succeeded in the Sadhana](http://www.sriramakrishna.in/2018/02/02/16-epilogue-of-the-masters-vedanta-sadhana-and-his-practice-of-islam/)

> Thought was immediately followed by action. The Master expressed his desire to Govinda, became  initiated and engaged himself in practising Islam according to its prescribed rules.
>
> The Master said, “I then devotionally repeated the holy syllable
> ‘Allah’, wore cloth like the Muslims, said Namaz thrice daily and felt
> disinclined even to see Hindu deities, not to speak of saluting them,
> inasmuch as the Hindu mode of thought vanished altogether from my
> mind. I spent three days in that mood, and had the full realization of
> the result of practices according to that faith.”
>
> At the time of practising Islam, the Master at first had the vision of
> an effulgent, impressive personage with a long beard; afterwards he
> had the knowledge of the all-pervading Brahman with attributes and
> merged finally in the attributeless Brahman, the Absolute.

***The behaviour of the Master at the time of practising Islam***

> At the time of practising Islam, ***the Master wanted, said Hriday(Sri Ramakrishna's nephew), to
> take Muslim food.*** It was Mathur’s solicitous request only that made
> him refrain from doing so.
>
> Knowing that the childlike Master would not abstain from it if that
> desire of his were not at least partially fulfilled, ***Mathur had a cook
> brought, under whose instruction a Brahmin cook prepared food in the
> Muslim manner, which was given to the Master to eat.***
>
> The Master did not even once enter the inner courtyard of the Kali
> temple while practising Islam, but remained in the mansion of Mathur
> situated outside.

---

So Sri Ramakrishna did not partake cow's meat during his practice of Islam.

Comment: I have read this. I was hoping maybe some other biography of Ramakrishna might have this incident Srila Prabhupada described. Btw is it true that Ramakrishna used to eat meat?

Comment: Also what does it mean by "Brahmin cook prepared food in the muslim manner"? What is this "muslim manner"?

Comment: @RishX: I could gather this material only.  May be Bengali literature may be having different versions, which can be known only if members who have gone through literature in Bengali language

Comment: No, he did not eat meat. VIvekananda says in his Complete Works that if goat meat/soup from a Kali sacrifice was offered to him as prasadam, he would dip his finger in it and put the dip from it on his forehead. Ramakrishna was a strict vegetarian..

Comment: @RishX Muslim manner might be "halal cooking"

Comment: By 'muslim manner' is meant adding onions into the food.

Comment: There's no such thing as 'Muslim food'. The only requirement is that it must be halal. Hence it's quite possible to be vegetarian and a Muslim at the same time.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv lets see if someone answers from bengali biographies of Ramakrishna.

Comment: @Panibotal doesn't halal mean meat ritualistically slaughtered in islamic ways?

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay really? So here muslim food is tamsic food? Is it mentioned somewhere?

Comment: @RishX halal isn't necessarily non veg. It can be veg too.

Comment: @Panibotal ohh I don't know much about halal.

Comment: Ramakrifshna's muslim phase was before 1866. At that time cooking beef and eating would have resulted in driving out both Ramakrishna and Mathur Biswas (Rani Rashmoni's son-in-law)  from the Kali Mandir. So Mathur Babu asked a Hindu cook to dress like a Muslim and cook standard vegetable food with lots of onions and garlic. This is mentioned in Swami Saradananda's magnum opus 'Ramakrishna the great master'.

Answer (score 0):

My recollection in reading the Gospel and the Divine Play was that Ramakrishna did eat meat once will practicing Islam. Also, he once swatted a mosquito. As a vegan I have difficulty in recognizing someone as divine involved in non ahimsa practice. In defense of Ramakrishna's actions, I can say he did these practices not for taste or sustenance, but for religious insight and to show his followers that sometimes pests must be exterminated for general well being. His action is truly divine in comparison to the Dalia Lama who is partial to baby cows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the English translation of 'Sri Ramakrishna - The great master by Swami Saradananda' by Swami Jagadananda. It tells us about the Master's Islamic phase.

> SRI RAMAKRISHNA - THE GREAT MASTER
> 2.16 EPILOGUE OF THE MASTER’S VEDANTA SADHANA AND HIS PRACTICE OF ISLAM
>
> 1. The severe disease of the Master and his unique behaviour at this time
>
> Now the Master’s strong body was shattered and he suffered from
> illness for a few months, either as a result of his curing the fatal
> disease of Jagadamba Dasi, as mentioned above, or of his superhuman
> efforts for six long months to dwell continually in the plane of the
> non-dual consciousness. We were told by him that he had then a severe
> attack of dysentery. His nephew Hriday engaged himself in nursing him
> day and night. Mathur placed him under the treatment of Gangaprasad
> Sen, the famous physician, and made special arrangements for his diet
> etc. Although his body was so severely ill, the extraordinary calmness
> and the incessant bliss enjoyed by his mind, freed from all
> body-consciousness, beggared description. His mind would separate
> itself from the body, the disease and all other objects of the world
> at the slightest suggestion,1 and would soar to the far-away
> Nirvikalpa plane at once. No sooner did it hear the word Brahman, Self
> or Isvara than it merged in its content, forgetting all other things
> and its own separate existence for some time. Therefore, it is clear,
> that in spite of that severe pain in his body owing to the fury of the
> disease, he actually felt very little of it. But that pain due to the
> disease, we heard from the Master himself, brought down his mind at
> times from high planes of spiritual experience and made it conscious
> of his body. The Master said it was during this period, that the
> foremost of the Paramahamsas, the followers of the Vedanta, used to
> come to him. His room was then always reverberating with the sounds of
> their utterances on the discussion of the Vedantic truths, “Not this,
> not this”, “Being-Revealing-Rejoicing”, “This Self in Brahman”2, and
> so on and so forth. When, during the discussions of those high
> Vedantic dicta, they could not arrive at the right conclusion on any
> question, the Master had to become the umpire and decide it. Need we
> say that had he been always distracted like other people on account of
> the disease, it would never have been possible for him constantly to
> take part in those abstruse philosophical discussions?
>
> 2. The Master’s auditive experience when he was established in the non-dual state. The results of that experience
>
> By the end of the period when he was continually in the Nirvikalpa
> plane, the Master had, we have said elsewhere,3 a wonderful auditive
> experience, a realization — he was now commanded for the third time
> “to remain in Bhavamukha” Though we call it an auditive experience,
> the reader should understand by it a realization in his heart of
> hearts. For, the Master did not hear it, unlike as he did twice
> before, from the mouth of any visible figure. But the Master’s mind
> had the immediate consciousness of the existence of that idea or will
> in the cosmic mind of the omnipresent Brahman, as it was remaining
> most of the time in complete oneness with the Absolute, the non-dual
> Being; and, at times, getting separated from It partially, was
> realizing that it was a part of the all-pervading Brahman with
> attributes, the Mother of the universe.4 On account of that
> realization, the future purpose of his life stood completely revealed
> to him.
>
> For, not standing in need of a body, nor at all desirous to continue
> in life, yet commanded again to “remain in Bhavamukha”, according to
> the inscrutable will of the universal Mother, the Master now came to
> know that he had to live in the body thenceforward in accordance with
> the will and purpose of the sportive Divine, and that he had been so
> commanded because his body could not continue to live, were he to
> remain eternally identified with Brahman. He also came to know his
> former lives, through Jatismaratwa (the power of remembering past
> lives) and that he was an Adhikarika person, or rather, an incarnation
> of God, eternally pure in nature, who now assumed a body and performed
> austerity etc., in order to rescue the modern age from the decline of
> religion and to bring about the well-being of humanity. He came to
> know, moreover, that, it was with a view to accomplishing some special
> purpose of Hers that the universal Mother had brought him down on
> earth into a poor Brahmin family, as one devoid of all grandeur of
> external powers. He came to know, further, that only a few people
> would be able to know and understand, during his lifetime, the mystery
> of that play of the divine Mother and that as soon as the generality
> of people would begin to understand it, the Mother would absorb Her
> child into Her own Person; but that the spiritual waves, which his
> body and mind would generate, would go on surging with ever greater
> momentum and would bring after his passing away plenitude of
> well-being to humanity for all time.
>
> 3. What the scriptures say about the attainment of the power of remembering previous lives just before realizing Brahman
>
> We must remember some of the statements in the scriptures, if we are
> to understand how the Master could have those extraordinary
> experiences. The aspirant, say the scriptures, attains Jatismaratwa5
> before he becomes fully established in the Pure Consciousness Itself
> with the help of the non-dual mood. In other words, with the fullest
> development of this remembrance, his memory reaches such a mature
> state that the entire history of his transmigration — how, where and
> how many times he had had to be encased in bodies and what actions,
> good or evil, he had performed — is revealed with a terrible
> vividness. Consequently, the transitoriness of everything in the world
> and the futility of the pursuit of worldly enjoyments, and of being
> born again and again under the same general conditions, are driven
> home to him. The intense detachment which then arises in his heart
> frees him from all desires whatsoever.
>
> 4. What the scriptures say about the attainment of Yogic powers, and the state in which all resolves come true
>
> The Upanishad6 says that the resolves of such persons always come
> true. And their minds through Samadhi can perceive any sphere they
> like, whether of gods or of forbears or of any other beings.
> Patanjali, the great sage, mentions in his Yoga-sutras that all kinds
> of Yogic powers are attained by such persons. Again, the author of the
> Panchadasi, synthesising this apparent contradiction coexisting in the
> same person viz., the attainment of Yogic powers and the absence of
> desires, says that although they attain such wonderful powers, they
> never apply them to further their own interests for the simple reason
> that they do not have any such desire. Absolutely dependent on the
> will of God, the Adhikarika persons alone amongst them apply at times
> those powers for the well-being of the many. That is why the author of
> the Panchadasi says that such a person has the power, but not the
> urge, to change the worldly circumstances in which he attains the
> knowledge of Brahman, and spends his time in that state.
>
> 5. The causes producing the Master’s extraordinary realization become understandable when we study his life in the light of the
>    above-mentioned sayings of the scriptures
>
> If one studies the Master’s life of this period in the light of the
> scriptural sayings quoted above, the how and why of most of the
> extraordinary realizations, if not all of them, stand fully revealed.
> One can understand how as a result of his whole-hearted offering of
> himself at the lotus feet of the divine Lord, he could attain perfect
> desirelessness and how in so short a time he ascended and firmly
> established himself in the Nirvikalpa plane of knowledge of Brahman.
> One can understand how he attained Jatismaratwa, as a result of which
> he had the immediate knowledge that the One, who had manifested
> Himself as Rama and Krishna in past ages and did good to humanity, had
> again assumed a body and manifested Himself in the present age as
> “Ramakrishna”7 One can understand why he never applied the divine
> powers for the comforts of his own body and mind, though their
> manifestations for the good of humanity were matters of almost daily
> occurrence; why he could and did awaken in others the power of
> realizing spiritual truths by a mere glance or wish; and why his
> extraordinary influence is slowly and surely spreading into and
> acquiring mastery over all the countries of the world.
>
> 6. Why the experiences mentioned before were not had simultaneously
>
> Thus did the Master know the past and future of his life at the time
> of his coming down to the realm of ideas from the non-dual state,
> though he was finally established in that state. But all those
> experiences do not seem to have come to him on one day or all of a
> sudden. He, we infer, had the perfect knowledge of all these things in
> a year after his coming down to the realm of ideas. During this time
> the Mother of the universe was removing, as it were, veil after veil
> from before his eyes, explaining clearly those things to him day after
> day. If we are asked why all those experiences were not revealed
> simultaneously to the Master’s mind, we reply that, established in the
> non-dual state of consciousness and completely lost in the bliss of
> Brahman, he had no time or inclination to know them, till the
> modification of his mind took an outward direction. Thus was fulfilled
> the Master’s earnest prayer to the Mother of the universe at the
> beginning of his Sadhana, “Mother, I do not know at all what I should
> do; I’ll learn what Thou Thyself wilt teach me.”
>
> 7. The realization of the Master that the attainment of the non-dual consciousness is the ultimate aim of all disciplines
>
> Firmly established in the plane of the non-dual consciousness, the
> Master had the realization of another fact also. He came to feel in
> his heart of hearts that the realization of non-duality was the
> ultimate aim of all kinds of disciplines. For, having performed
> Sadhanas according to the teachings of all the main religious
> denominations prevalent in India, he had already been convinced that
> they all took the aspirants towards the non-dual plane. Asked about
> the non-dual state, he, therefore, said to us over and over again, “It
> is the finale, my child, the acme, which comes of itself in the life
> of all aspirants as the ultimate development of their love of God.
> Know it to be the last word of all faiths, and the faiths are only
> paths (and not the goal).”
>
> 8. The abovementioned realization of the Master was never fully grasped by anyone before
>
> Having thus had the direct experience of non-duality, the Master’s
> mind was filled with unbounded catholicity. He had now an
> extraordinary sympathy for all the religious communities which taught
> that the aim of human life was the realization of God. But he did not
> realize at first that the said catholicity and sympathy were his
> discoveries8 and that no aspirant, not even the foremost of them, in
> the past could attain them as fully as he. He (such is our impression)
> became gradually acquainted with that fact by coming in contact with
> the wise Sadhakas belonging to various religious communities at the
> Kali temple at Dakshineswar and at other well-known places of
> pilgrimage. But, thenceforward, he was very much wounded whenever he
> came across one-sidedness in religion, and he tried in all ways to
> remove that mean attitude.
>
> 9. The Master’s practice of Islam, an example of the liberality of his mind established in the nondual knowledge
>
> We can clearly understand from an event of this time how liberal the
> Master’s mind which was firmly poised in the non-dual knowledge, now
> became. The Master, we have seen, was ill for a few months after he
> had reached the zenith in the Practice of the non-dual mood. The event
> came to pass when he had come round. A short time previously one
> Govinda Ray had been in search of truth for some time. Hriday told us
> that he was a Kshatriya by birth. He was perhaps learned in Persian
> and Arabic. Having studied various religious doctrines and come in
> contact with different religious communities, he was at last attracted
> by the liberal doctrine of Islam and was formally initiated into it.
> Govinda, thirsting for truth, accepted the Islamic faith, but we
> cannot say how far he followed its social manners and customs. But,
> since he became initiated, he, we were told, engaged himself ardently
> in the reading of the Koran and in religious practices according to
> the process prescribed by that scripture. Govinda was an ardent lover
> of God. The method of worshipping God according to the teaching and
> mental attitude prevalent amongst the Sufis, followers of a sect of
> Islam, seems to have captivated his mind; for he now became engaged
> day and night in practising devotional moods like the Dervishes, the
> devotees belonging to that sect.
>
> 10. The arrival of the Sufi Govinda Ray
>
> Somehow or other Govinda now came to the Kali temple at Dakshineswar
> and began to spend his time there with his “seat” spread under the
> peaceful shade of the Panchavati, which he thought, was a place
> favourable to religious practices. Muslim Fakirs, as well as Hindu
> Sadhus, who had renounced the world, were welcome at Rasmani’s Kali
> temple and the hospitality of the temple was equally accorded to both
> of them Therefore, while staying there Govinda had not to go round for
> alms. He spent his days joyfully meditating on his chosen Ideal.
>
> 11. The Master’s resolve afer talking with Govinda
>
> The Master was attracted towards the devout Govinda, and happening to
> converse with him, was charmed with Govinda’s sincere faith in and
> love for God. Thus was the Master’s mind now attracted towards the
> Islamic religion. “This also”, thought he, “is a path to the
> realization of God; the sportive Mother, the source of infinite Lila,
> has been blessing many people with the attainment of Her lotus feet
> through this path also. I must see how through it She makes those who
> take refuge in Her, attain their desired end. I’ll be initiated by
> Govinda and engage myself in the practice of that spiritual mood.”
>
> 12. Initiated by Govinda, the Master succeeded in the Sadhana
>
> Thought was immediately followed by action. The Master expressed his
> desire to Govinda, became initiated and engaged himself in practising
> Islam according to its prescribed rules. The Master said, “I then
> devotionally repeated the holy syllable ‘Allah’, wore cloth like the
> Muslims, said Namaz thrice daily and felt disinclined even to see
> Hindu deities, not to speak of saluting them, inasmuch as the Hindu
> mode of thought vanished altogether from my mind. I spent three days
> in that mood, and had the full realization of the result of practices
> according to that faith.” At the time of practising Islam, the Master
> at first had the vision of an effulgent, impressive personage with a
> long beard; afterwards he had the knowledge of the all-pervading
> Brahman with attributes and merged finally in the attributeless
> Brahman, the Absolute.
>
> 13. **The behaviour of the Master at the time of practising Islam**
>
> **At the time of practising Islam, the Master wanted, said Hriday, to
> take Muslim food. It was Mathur’s solicitous request only that made
> him refrain from doing so. Knowing that the childlike Master would not
> abstain from it if that desire of his were not at least partially
> fulfilled, Mathur had a cook brought, under whose instruction a
> Brahmin cook prepared food in the Muslim manner, which was given to
> the Master to eat.** The Master did not even once enter the inner
> courtyard of the Kali temple while practising Islam, but remained in
> the mansion of Mathur situated outside.

Sri Ramakrishna - The Great Master by Swami Saradananda translated by Swami Jagadananda